# Rails 4: Trying to add subscriber to Mailchimp list on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp

I am simply trying add a subscriber to my newsletter mailing list that I have set up on Mailchimp using the `after_create` callback.

I'm getting a routing error "undefined method `after_create' for Users::RegistrationsController:Class" when I try to go to "users/edit" page. This is what I have:

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
after_create :add_newsletter_subscriber

 def create
  # create method
 end

private

 def add_newsletter_subscriber
  mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
  mailchimp.lists.subscribe('[newsletter-list-id]', {
    "email" => @user.email        
  },
  merge_vars: {"FIRSTNAME" => @user.first_name,
                    "LASTNAME" => @user.last_name}
            )
end
```

For the `add_newsletter_subscriber` method, I'm referring to [this documentation on mailchimp](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby/overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback should take place in your ActiveRecord model not in the controller. The `after_create` callback is only available in your models.

See 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

There are also controller callbacks available

```
after_action, append_after_action, 
append_around_action, append_before_action, around_action
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html

But in your case you should move this code into your User model.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I'm getting "undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass" on `@user.email`

Comment: In your model you would not reference the instance variable of @user. Instead you would use `self.email`

Comment: Aha! Thank you, Jason.